# android app does not show up on my device or the emulator in eclipse

Tags: android, console, logcat

hey everyone,
I have no errors in my app-code what so ever, but when i try to run in on either my cell or my emulator/the avd in eclipse i can't run it because it doesn't show up on either one.
this is my console output:

```
[2011-02-04 08:14:58 - Versuch] Uploading Versuch.apk onto device 'CB511L2WTB'
[2011-02-04 08:14:58 - Versuch] Installing Versuch.apk...
[2011-02-04 08:15:01 - Versuch] Success!
[2011-02-04 08:15:01 - Versuch] \Versuch\bin\Versuch.apk installed on device
[2011-02-04 08:15:01 - Versuch] Done!
```

and this is my LogCat output, which tells me nothing, but you are the experts ;)

```
    02-04 08:18:10.020: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2576 objects / 559120 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:18:10.700: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7692 objects / 478912 bytes in 41ms
02-04 08:18:11.170: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31774): GC freed 3367 objects / 163464 bytes in 122ms
02-04 08:18:13.230: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2790 objects / 552328 bytes in 38ms
02-04 08:18:14.650: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 8443 objects / 540440 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:18:16.260: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31921): GC freed 214 objects / 9824 bytes in 216ms
02-04 08:18:16.670: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3232 objects / 561256 bytes in 40ms
02-04 08:18:18.600: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7718 objects / 481952 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:18:19.210: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 6898 objects / 275328 bytes in 109ms
02-04 08:18:19.690: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2968 objects / 571232 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:18:21.440: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1212): GC freed 1020 objects / 49328 bytes in 395ms
02-04 08:18:22.570: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7893 objects / 495616 bytes in 40ms
02-04 08:18:23.060: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3117 objects / 561912 bytes in 41ms
02-04 08:18:25.860: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2924 objects / 558448 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:18:26.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32098): GC freed 4662 objects / 495496 bytes in 290ms
02-04 08:18:26.410: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 1077 objects / 130680 bytes in 33ms
02-04 08:18:27.080: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7912 objects / 485368 bytes in 40ms
02-04 08:18:28.190: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 953 objects / 767272 bytes in 33ms
02-04 08:18:29.500: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 6756 objects / 270480 bytes in 105ms
02-04 08:18:30.500: WARN/System.err(22536): java.lang.Exception: You must call com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize() first
02-04 08:18:30.670: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.ProductConfiguration.getProductName(ProductConfiguration.java:136)
02-04 08:18:30.670: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.api.rest.Item.getPublishingContainersItems(Item.java:15)
02-04 08:18:30.670: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.getContainerFromServer(ContainerHelper.java:68)
02-04 08:18:30.670: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.run(ContainerHelper.java:46)
02-04 08:18:31.090: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 10545 objects / 682480 bytes in 49ms
02-04 08:18:31.120: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1813): GC freed 5970 objects / 310912 bytes in 60ms
02-04 08:18:31.320: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2468 objects / 539520 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:18:34.110: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2879 objects / 569008 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:34.920: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7029 objects / 424632 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:36.150: DEBUG/dalvikvm(9060): GC freed 564 objects / 27840 bytes in 89ms
02-04 08:18:36.630: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2437 objects / 554000 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:38.760: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 8309 objects / 545032 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:18:39.270: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 6958 objects / 278352 bytes in 107ms
02-04 08:18:39.970: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2915 objects / 560312 bytes in 38ms
02-04 08:18:41.260: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6184): GC freed 373 objects / 26152 bytes in 205ms
02-04 08:18:42.780: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7212 objects / 447696 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:18:43.160: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3106 objects / 561824 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:18:46.310: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3110 objects / 564080 bytes in 45ms
02-04 08:18:46.650: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7508 objects / 468832 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:18:48.820: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31712): GC freed 13795 objects / 828232 bytes in 203ms
02-04 08:18:49.040: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 6918 objects / 276224 bytes in 109ms
02-04 08:18:49.640: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2952 objects / 562168 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:18:50.630: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 8332 objects / 549680 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:52.770: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3108 objects / 563192 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:18:54.400: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7509 objects / 469016 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:55.900: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3121 objects / 572920 bytes in 38ms
02-04 08:18:58.150: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7408 objects / 465456 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:18:58.710: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 6908 objects / 276440 bytes in 107ms
02-04 08:18:59.190: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3160 objects / 563144 bytes in 38ms
02-04 08:19:02.080: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7436 objects / 468040 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:02.380: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3104 objects / 557600 bytes in 39ms
02-04 08:19:05.050: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2860 objects / 570072 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:19:05.810: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7508 objects / 469080 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:19:06.500: DEBUG/skia(22167): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-04 08:19:07.960: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2747 objects / 520008 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:08.180: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 7866 objects / 317304 bytes in 107ms
02-04 08:19:09.540: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 8220 objects / 539688 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:10.810: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2898 objects / 596824 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:19:13.360: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2503 objects / 398936 bytes in 35ms
02-04 08:19:13.370: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(22167): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.029MB for 570264-byte allocation
02-04 08:19:13.400: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 702 objects / 24976 bytes in 31ms
02-04 08:19:13.400: DEBUG/skia(22167): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-04 08:19:13.540: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7481 objects / 466544 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:15.600: DEBUG/WifiService(1129): got ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE
02-04 08:19:15.960: INFO/wpa_supplicant(2522): CTRL-EVENT-DRIVER-STATE STOPPED
02-04 08:19:15.960: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1129): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DRIVER-STATE STOPPED]
02-04 08:19:17.270: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 2372 objects / 1266992 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:17.520: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7996 objects / 519128 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:19:18.150: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1129): GC freed 7110 objects / 285032 bytes in 108ms
02-04 08:19:20.460: DEBUG/dalvikvm(22167): GC freed 3327 objects / 565264 bytes in 36ms
02-04 08:19:21.250: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6709): GC freed 7632 objects / 486024 bytes in 37ms
02-04 08:19:26.470: DEBUG/dalvikvm(31774): GC freed 345 objects / 16160 bytes in 96ms
02-04 08:19:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536): java.lang.Exception: You must call com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize() first
02-04 08:19:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.ProductConfiguration.getProductName(ProductConfiguration.java:136)
02-04 08:19:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.api.rest.Item.getPublishingContainersItems(Item.java:15)
02-04 08:19:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.getContainerFromServer(ContainerHelper.java:68)
02-04 08:19:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.run(ContainerHelper.java:46)
02-04 08:20:05.280: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1813): GC freed 741 objects / 36840 bytes in 91ms
02-04 08:20:23.580: DEBUG/WifiService(1129): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
02-04 08:20:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536): java.lang.Exception: You must call com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize() first
02-04 08:20:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.ProductConfiguration.getProductName(ProductConfiguration.java:136)
02-04 08:20:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.api.rest.Item.getPublishingContainersItems(Item.java:15)
02-04 08:20:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.getContainerFromServer(ContainerHelper.java:68)
02-04 08:20:30.423: WARN/System.err(22536):     at com.mercuryintermedia.mflow.ContainerHelper.run(ContainerHelper.java:46)
02-04 08:20:53.970: INFO/FastDormancyManager(1129): Fast Dormant executed. ExecuteCount:2683 NonExecuteCount:25773
```

I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must call
>   com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize()
>   first

This is a quote from your logcat. Don't know what is

> ProductConfiguration

but you should call initialize() method firstly in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Theres is no initialization done for the code in your "ProductConfiguration". As the error message gives the information:

```
WARN/System.err(22536): java.lang.Exception: You must call
com.mercuryintermedia.productconfiguration.initialize() first
WARN/System.err(22536): at com.mercuryintermedia.ProductConfiguration.getProductName
(ProductConfiguration.java:136)
```

Can you put up the code at the line 136 here ? for more clarification?
Check if the Main class is mentioned in the Manifest file.